# sh-mode: Correctly indent and highlight inside bash's subshell substitution $()?

Tags: indentation, syntax-highlighting, bash

I noticed that bash will correctly apply syntax highlighting inside the subshell substitution in

```
VALUE="Hello $(echo World)."
```

But when creating a more complicated value, e.g.

```
VALUE="Hello $(
    echo good
    echo world
)."
```

the commands inside the subshell will be highlighted as string-contents, and indentation will behave as text-mode indentation. Indentation works correctly when writing something like

```
VALUE="Hello "$(
    echo good
    echo world
)"."
```

but this changes the semantics, unless IFS is set to the empty string.

Is there some way to fix this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "correctly apply code".  AFAIK it only highlights the `echo` right after `$(` but doesn't find the `sed` in `"foo $(echo toto | sed titi)"`.  I think this "feature"'s implementation is very naive and would need to be completely rewritten.  As for indentation, it's a completely separate question.  I suggest you file those two issues as feature requests via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @Stefan Fixed the wording from "code" to "syntax highlighting".

Comment: Seems the implementation assumes, that "quoted exec" (``"`cmd`"``, ``"$(cmd)"``) always consist of a single command only. Easiest way to avoid the issues, seems to be writing scripts with `IFS=''`...